# How to automatically start programs in a specific order?

Tags: i3

I have these lines in my i3 configuration file:

```
# Startup applications.
exec firefox
exec gnome-terminal
exec nautilus
```

These lines start firefox, gnome-terminal and nautilus as expected, but the order in which they start is unpredictable. Is there a way to start these applications in a way that makes the windows appear in the order that I want? (i.e. firefox, then gnome-terminal, then nautilus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Layout saving in i3](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html).

Add this to the i3 configuration file:

```
# Create specific layout for applications.
exec --no-startup-id "i3-msg 'workspace 1; append_layout ~/.config/i3/workspace-1.json'"
# Start applications.
exec firefox
exec gnome-terminal
```

Create `~/.config/i3/workspace-1.json`:

```
// Layout of a workspace.
{
    "layout": "tabbed",
    // To get a window's class name, run xprop and click on the window.
    // You will see the following output:
    //     WM_CLASS(STRING) = "InstanceName", "ClassName"
    // Alternatively, "swallow" by the window's title.
    "nodes": [
        {"swallows": [{"class": "^Firefox$"}]},
        {"swallows": [{"class": "^Gnome-terminal$"}]}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [save layouts](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) so that each application is captured by a predefined window container. Making it truly automatic requires a little extra scripting. Examples from my configuration:

### i3 config

```sh
assign [class="^Vivaldi-stable$"] 1
assign [class="^Keepassx2$"] 2
assign [class="^Thunderbird$"] 2

....

# last line
exec ~/.config/i3/restore.sh &
```

### restore.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for layout in ~/.config/i3/layouts/*; do
  i3-msg "workspace $(basename "$layout" .json); append_layout $layout"
done

(vivaldi-stable &)
(keepassxc &)
(thunderbird &)
```

If you want to see the full version, my dotfiles are [on GitHub](https://github.com/dmfay/dotfiles/tree/master/i3).

Comment: Is there a way to make a specified window get the final focus? For example, I may want thunderbird to automatically get the focus after all programs have started.

Comment: Use [i3-msg](https://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-msg.html): end the restore script with a call to `i3-msg '[class="^Thunderbird$"] focus'`.